# How to make item in a cart not to display when it has order_number attached

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

I have a  project am working on, in the project item(s) can be added to the cart. When checked-out an order is created with an order_number tied to all item(s) in the cart at that session.
If more items were added to the cart after when an order have been created and the cart is viewed, it shows items that were has order_number attached and and the new items that were added.

How do i make items that have order_number attached not to display in the cart since an order_number has been attached to it when it was checked-out.

Here is my views.py

```
@login_required()
def cart(request):
    request_user = request.user

    items = Cart.objects.filter(client=request_user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        print "rp ", request.POST
        docfile = request.POST['docfile']
        print "Docfile", docfile
        description = request.POST['description']
        print "Description is ", description
        price = request.POST['price']
        print "Price is ", price
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        print "Quantity is ", quantity
        client = request.user
        print "Client is ", client

        item, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(client=client, description=description, price=price, quantity=quantity)
        item.save()

    return render(request, 'selly/cart.html', {'items': items})


@login_required
def order(request):
    order_number = create_id()
    print "ORDER NUMBER", order_number
    request_user = request.user
    all_items = Cart.objects.filter(client=request_user, ordered=False)
    print "ALL ITEM", all_items
    if request.method == "POST":
        client = request.user
        # print "Client is ", client
        location=request.user.signup.country
        # print "LOCATION ", location

        item, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(order_number=order_number, client=client, location=location)
        item.save()

    order = Order.objects.filter(order_number = order_number)
    print "ORDER", order
    all_items.update(ordered = True, order = order[0])
    my_order = Order.objects.filter(client=request_user) #Populate client's Order to template
    return render(request, "selly/order.html", {'my_order': my_order, 'order': order})
```

Here is my Models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def total(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity


class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = PAYMENT_STATUS, default='Pending')
    shipment_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = SHIPMENT_STATUS, default='Pending')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_number
```

Comment: I would keep and display them in the cart until the checkout is completed (paid) and then delete them from the cart once they become an actual order.

Comment: i intend doing it so that a user can have different orders